# Permission issues after moving from folder from one partition to another

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, permissions

I am using ubuntu.

I moved all my C programs/coded which was in a folder from one partition to another, after that all my files have `-rw-------` the owner has just the read and write permission, even though I used `chmod 777` on all my files the permission remains the same `-rw-------`. I also tried `chown`. I tried both the commands as superuser.

Due to this permission change I can't run any of my executable. Even when I compile and generate the executable it still has the same `-rw-------` permission.

How can i change the permissions now? How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Is the destination folder on an NTFS partition?

Comment: @Jobin: Its a NTFS partition, i actually moved my folder from home directory to another partions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the partition you need to change, not the actual files and folders.

You need to first make sure the directory where you mount the partition has the correct permissions, using the normal methods that you seem familiar with.

Next, how are you mounting the partition?  If you are using `/etc/fstab`, you need to set options for that partition.

If it's ext3 or ext4, you can use `defaults,user_xattr`.

NTFS is more complicated, and I don't actually have one to check, but it's something like:
`defaults,dmask=027,fmask=137,umask=007`  and sometimes you need to set the owner and group IDs (something like `uid=1000,gid=1000` added to the list.  But there are a lot of variations, depending on your needs and tastes.  Like, do you want to be the owner, or do you want to be in a group that has certain permissions?  Best to look up the mount command or fstab to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount your NTFS partition as follows:

```
sudo mkdir /media/$USER/device_label
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/device /media/$USER/device_label
```

change `/dev/device` to the NTFS partition device, eg. `/dev/sda2` or whatever you have.